# Measure to calculate Expense as a % of Revenue for Prior Year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to calculate percentage of a filtered total, specifically income statement expense by IS_Grp as a percentage of revenue.  I have a working % of revenue measure for for current year % of revenue, but I can't seem to get the measure for % of revenue for prior year to calculate.

I have successfully created Expense & Revenue measures:

```
Expense = CALCULATE(SUM('GL Data'[Amount]),FILTER('GL Data','GL Data'[SubGrp1] = "EXPENSE"))
Revenue = CALCULATE(SUM('GL Data'[Amount]),FILTER('GL Data','GL Data'[SubGrp1] = "REVENUE"))
```

I have successfully created Expense and Revenue measures for prior year:

```
Expense PY = CALCULATE([Expense], DATEADD(Dates[Date],-1,YEAR))
Revenue PY = CALCULATE([Revenue], DATEADD(Dates[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

This is the % or Revenue for current year that works:

```
% of Rev = DIVIDE([Expense],CALCULATE([Revenue],FILTER(ALLSELECTED('GL Data'),'GL Data'[SubGrp1] = "REVENUE")),0)
```

This measure for prior year **does not work**.  This results in no data:

```
% of Rev PY = DIVIDE([Expense PY],CALCULATE([Revenue PY],FILTER(ALLSELECTED('GL Data'),'GL Data'[SubGrp1] = "REVENUE")),0)
```

Here is the current visual for reference.

[image]

Comment: Are Expense PY and Revenue PY giving out the right values?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving accurate values for Expense PY and Revenue PY.  % of Rev is also showing accurate percentages.